# Modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, error

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autolayout

I did ask this question before and got an answer but I am still getting the same error message when I run it on my device.

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release. Stack :(

The code I am running is below

```
import UIKit

class BallPitchingViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIWebView!

var time = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "load", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

func load() {

    let youTubeUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/behrfv14zX0"
    videoView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true


        self.videoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width=\"\(self.videoView.frame.width)\" height=\"\(self.videoView.frame.height)\" src=\"\(youTubeUrl)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", baseURL: nil)
        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")


}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from this file? and if so, show more of the code. For example I see: `// Do any additional setup after loading the view.` what is happening here?

Comment: Basically I have a static tableview that leads to an embed Youtube video in a UIWebView. The rest of the code is the bog standard code is swift. ` // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }`